# Spring fails to parse OffsetDateTime as rest service parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, java-17

```
Springboot 3.0.3
OpenJdk-17
```

I have a service method with OffsetDateTime as parameter.

```
@GetMapping("/transaction/search/bydate")
public String searchTransactions(
        @RequestParam("fromDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) OffsetDateTime fromDate)
{
    logger.debug("Request received!");
    return "Received " + fromDate.toString();
}
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Springboot throws error when calling the service:

```
curl localhost:8080/transaction/search/another?fromDate=2022-05-09T01:30:00.000-5:00
```

The error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-02-23T21:44:12.191+00:00",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "path": "/transaction/search/another"
}
```

Log file has following error:

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to  com.example.demo.RestController#searchTransactions(Optional, OffsetDateTime)
o.s.beans.TypeConverterDelegate          : Field [2022-05-09T01:30:00.000-5:00] isn't an enum value
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: 2022-05-09T01:30:00.000-5:00
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:2117) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.attemptToConvertStringToEnum(TypeConverterDelegate.java:308) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:215) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:53) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:729) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
....
```

If I change the parameter to LocalDateTime, it works fine if I take out the offset from the request. I tried adding ObjectMapper and custom json serializer. Also tried adding custom conversion service. Nothing seem to work.

I tried following as suggested in other threads:

1. Added custom ObjectMapper
   @Configuration
   public class JsonConfiguration {

   ```
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER =
          new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()) 
        .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        return OBJECT_MAPPER;
    }
   ```
2. Added custom conversion service by extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport

   ```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar dateTimeRegistrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        dateTimeRegistrar.setDateFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        dateTimeRegistrar.setDateTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
        dateTimeRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

        DateFormatterRegistrar dateRegistrar = new DateFormatterRegistrar();
        dateRegistrar.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        dateRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

        return conversionService;
    }
   ```
3. Tried setting Jackon2ObjectMapperBuilder as suggested in anther thread

   ```
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {

        return builder -> {

            // formatter
            DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            // deserializers
            builder.deserializers(new OffsetDateTimeDeserializer());

            // serializers
            builder.serializers(new OffsetDateTimeSerializer());
        };
    }
   ```

If nothing works, I might have to change parameter type to String and manually validate/convert string to OffsetDateTime value in the method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution which works for me

1.Create a class which extends PropertyEditorSupport. Define there how you want to translate the property.

```
public class OffsetDateTimeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        Object value = getValue();
        return value == null ? "" : value.toString(); //replace this line
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            setValue(null);
        } else {
            OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(); //replace this line
            setValue(now);
        }
    }
}
```

2.Add binding to this property to your Controller class:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(OffsetDateTime.class,
            new OffsetDateTimeEditor());
}
```

I tested it with spring 3.0.3 and Java 19.